# Raspberry Pi Zero saying "No Wireless LAN Interface found"?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, dhcp, internet-connection

I am working with others and I need to connect the Raspberry Pi Zero to my WiFi then give it a static IP so that we can SSH into it. The others in the group have successfully done so.

I started by manually setting an IP for the Raspberry Pi through the router settings then I followed the steps in this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/LCJtUbRlIXE) to give it the static IP, before having logged it into the network.

I realized this then followed the instructions in [this article](https://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-connect-your-raspberry-pi-to-wifi/) to try to add it through the system files (should have just gotten a mouse and used the GUI instead).

This did not work so I got a mouse and tried to use the GUI instead only to be met with "No Wirelesss LAN instances found", then I opened up the Wireless Internet settings then hit clear and apply (since the IP I tried to set there was in the fields and I wanted to try by removing the static IP settings just in case that was messing something up). Now when I go back to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, the file is empty (the file still exists, but its like everything inside of it has been deleted).

I have created a fresh instance of Raspberry Pi Os on a separate card, and that was able to see my WiFi. We have work stored on this Raspberry Pi Zero, so I am looking to restore the OS's ability to see WiFi and to give it a static IP. I am fairly new to Linux.

Does anyone have any advice, know caused `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to become an empty file, and/or know how to get this OS instance be able to see WiFi again?

FWIW, I took pictures of the default `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` code and copied it character by character into the empty `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file. This *did not* fix the Raspberry Pi’s inability to detect internet and the Raspberry  Pi is still displaying "No Wireless LAN instances found".

When hovering over the network settings, it says:

```
Wlan0 not associated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided to do a fresh install of the OS on the Raspberry Pi, as that will fix the issue. We do not know what caused it nor do we know another solution.